MS Access pick an image in a continuous form
I have a continuous form, in the table I have a field with the path of an image, so in the form I set that field to an image control and it shows the image, that works great.
But I want to click on the image and pick another file. I put the code in the click event of the image control, but when I click the image it didn't change the focus to the row, so it allways change the image in the selected row instead of change it in the row where I clicked the image. If I put a button, when you click the button it first change the focus and then runs the click event, but it doesn't work in an image control, and I'm not sure how to do to make it works.
This is my code
Private Sub Imagen37_Click()
    Dim fDialog As Office.FileDialog
    Dim varFile As Variant

   Set fDialog = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFilePicker)
   With fDialog
  
      .Title = "Seleccione un archivo de imagen" 
      .Filters.Clear
      .Filters.Add "Imagenes", "*.png; *.jpg; *.bmp"
      .Filters.Add "All Files", "*.*"

   If .Show = True Then
   For Each varFile In .SelectedItems
       ' Me![photoideaframe].Picture = strPathAndFile
       Me![Imagen] = varFile
       '  Me.Imagen = varFile
       Next
     
       Else
           MsgBox "Has cancelado sin elegir archivo."
       End If
    End With
End Sub

I try to use a button, but when I set the picture in the button it don't fit the button, but show me only a little part of it, I don't know if there are any way to make it fit the image in the button.
